# How to put a button or textbox on an excel worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

does anyone know how to place buttons or textboxes on worksheet with vba or manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always helps to know which version of Excel you're working in.

In Excel 2003, right-click any toolbar and enable the Forms toolbar. Select the Button from there. This type of button can be assigned to a macro so that when someone clicks it, the macro is executed.

In Excel 2007, go to the Excel menu and select Excel Options. Select Popular and then check the Show Developer Ribbon option. On the Developer ribbon, select the Insert... pulldown and you'll be able to do basically the same series of steps as above.

HTH,
Neb

Comment: its about time someone answered this question!!! ive been waiting two days and been reposting it

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2013 add the "Insert controls" to the quick access toolbar.

select the drop-down arrow from the insert controls, then choose the control you wish to add to the worksheet (double click on that control to add code to it).